# TYPO3 Language Switch with FLUID

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript, fluid, viewhelper

I've made a language menu (switch) for `TYPO3 7.6` with `Fluid` only, no `TypoScript`. Just a Dropdown, see screenshot below. I also used the `Ext:vhs`, here's my code example:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<ul id="languageMenu" class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>  
    <!-- german L:0 -->
    <f:if condition="{v:page.language()}==0">
        <li class="de">
            <f:link.page pageUid="{page.uid}" additionalParams="{L:0}">
                <f:image src="EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Flags/de.svg" width="18" height="14" alt="" />
                <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:language.de" />
            </f:link.page>
            <ul class="menu languageSubMenu">
                <li class="en">
                    <f:link.page pageUid="{page.uid}" additionalParams="{L:1}">
                        <f:image src="EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Flags/gb.svg" width="18" height="14" alt="" />
                        <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:language.en" />
                    </f:link.page>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </f:if>


    <!-- english L:1 -->
    <f:if condition="{v:page.language()}==1">
        <li class="en">
            <f:link.page pageUid="{page.uid}" additionalParams="{L:1}">
                <f:image src="EXT:hellocode/Resources/Public/Icons/Flags/gb.svg" width="18" height="14"
                         alt="{f:translate(key: 'LLL:EXT:hellocode/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:language.en')}" />
                <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:language.en" />
            </f:link.page>
            <ul class="menu languageSubMenu">
                <li class="de">
                    <f:link.page pageUid="{page.uid}" additionalParams="{L:0}">
                        <f:image src="EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Flags/de.svg" width="18" height="14" alt="" />
                        <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:language.de" />
                    </f:link.page>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </f:if>
</ul>
```

At the moment the language switch is always shown. If there's no page translation, I'll get an 404 Error. Of course, the missing page aren't exist. How can I hide my language switch, if there's no translation?

In past I used `USERDEF1` with `TypoScript`, but I need a solution with `Fluid`. I also see there's a viewhelper [v:condition.page.isLanguage](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Condition/Page/IsLanguageViewHelper.html) but this isn't working for me or I don't know how?! Is it possible to do this with [Fluid](https://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid) or `vhs`?

I would be grateful for any advice. Otherwise I have to write typoscript again ...

[image: frontend language switcher]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need extension for that. The viewhelpers languageMenu is enough.

Here the code I use, ok for accessibility, working with bootstrap 4 :

```
<div class="navbar-nav mr-auto dropdown show">
            <v:page.languageMenu
              hideNotTranslated="1" 
              order="0,1,2,3" 
              layout="name" 
              defaultLanguageLabel="Français"
              defaultIsoFlag="fr"
              labelOverwrite="FR,EN,NL,ES"
              as="menu">
    
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <f:for each="{menu}" as="langMenu">
                  <li class="nav-item>
                    <f:if condition="{langMenu.current}=1">
                        <f:link.page pageUid="{page.uid}"
                        id="dropdownMenuLink" 
                        class="dropdown-toggle nav-link lang px-3 flag-nav--{langMenu.flag}"
                        additionalAttributes="{data-toggle:'dropdown', aria-haspopup:'true', aria-expanded:'false'}"
                        lang="{f:if(condition: '{langMenu.current}=1', then: '{langMenu.flag}')}"
                        title="<f:switch expression='{langMenu.flag}'>
                                    <f:case value='fr'>français actif, changer de langue</f:case>
                                    <f:case value='gb'>english activate, modify language</f:case>
                                    <f:case value='nl'>Engels activeren, taal wijzigen</f:case>
                                    <f:case value='es'>Español activo, cambio de idioma</f:case>
                                </f:switch>"
                        >
                            {langMenu.label}
                        </f:link.page>
                    </f:if>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" aria-expended="false">
                        
                        <f:for each="{menu}" as="langMenu">
                            <f:switch expression='{langMenu.flag}'>
                                <f:case value='fr'>{v:variable.set(value: '0', name: 'langparam')}</f:case>
                                <f:case value='gb'>{v:variable.set(value: '1', name: 'langparam')}</f:case>
                                <f:case value='nl'>{v:variable.set(value: '2', name: 'langparam')}</f:case>
                                <f:case value='nl'>{v:variable.set(value: '3', name: 'langparam')}</f:case>
                            </f:switch>
                            
                            <li>
                            

                                <f:link.page pageUid="{page.uid}"
                                class="dropdown-item"
                                lang="{langMenu.flag}"
                                title="<f:switch expression='{langMenu.flag}'>
                                            <f:case value='fr'>Passer le site en français</f:case>
                                            <f:case value='gb'>Go to english version</f:case>
                                            <f:case value='nl'>Ga naar de nederlandse versie</f:case>
                                            <f:case value='es'>Salta el sitio en español</f:case>
                                        </f:switch>"
                                additionalParams="{L:'{langparam}'}"
                                >
                                    {langMenu.label}
                                </f:link.page>
                            </li>
                        </f:for>
                        
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </f:for>
              </ul>
            </v:page.languageMenu>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only propose to use https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_language_menu

You can simply use it like that: https://bitbucket.org/reelworx/rx-typo3-sitesetup/src/e34b675a223f02580838fe7d5d118d7f07fd8a68/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Default.html-48

Of course it is fully Fluid based, so you can override all templates to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip. Mmhh two extensions (`static_info_tables` & `sr_language_menu`) for a language menu? I usually try to do it myself, or maybe with typoscript.

Comment: `static_info_tables` is more or less installed in almost any TYPO3 instance we run. Most of our forms with a country selector require it anyways.

Comment: ok, you're right. I give the Ext. sr_language;menu a chance. Thank you. But it will be nice, if I can find a solution via FLUID ... without extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vhs and the ViewHelpers LanguageMenu

```
[https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/LanguageMenuViewHelper.html][1]
```